# Insert data into database using jQuery ajax without postback in ASP.NET C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, ajax, c#-4.0

I am working on a project that requires using jQuery ajax for data submissions into a SQL Server database. I am used to submitting data using post-backs. When I try submitting, I keep getting an error in submission! In the jQuery file instead of the successful message and data is not inserted. Please what am I doing wrong? Also, please find below my aspx page, jQuery script, class and webmethod in asmx:

My ASPX PAGE:

```
<div id="sf6" class="frm" style="display: none;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Bank Account Information [Step 6 of 7]</legend>


        <div class="form-group">
            <%--<label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="uname">Subject 1: </label>--%>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div style="color: #b94a48; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; background-color: #f2dede; border: #eed3d7 1px solid; padding: 10px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <p>
                        <b>Important Info:</b>PLEASE SUPPLY YOUR PERSONAL ACTIVE ACCOUNT DETAILS.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="uname">Bank: </label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlbankname" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="330px">
                    <asp:ListItem>--Select Bank--</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Access Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Access (Diamond)Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>CitiBank Nigeria Limited</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Ecobank Nigeria Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Enterprise Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Fidelity Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>First Bank Nigeria Limited</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>First City Monument Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Globus Bank Limited</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Guaranty Trust Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Heritage Banking Company Limited</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Jaiz Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Keystone Bank</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>MainStreet Bank</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Polaris Bank</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Providus Bank</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Skye Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Stanbic IBTC Ltd</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Standard Chartered Bank Nig Ltd</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Sterling Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>SunTrust Bank Nigeria Limited</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Titan Trust Bank Limited</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Union Bank of Nigeria Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>United Bank For Africa Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Unity Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Wema Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Zenith Bank Plc</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="uname">Account No: </label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" ID="txtaccno" Width="330px" placeholder="*Account Number" value="" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="txtsortcode">Sort Code: </label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" ID="txtsortcode" Width="330px" placeholder="Sort Code(Optional)" value=""></asp:TextBox>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <asp:Button ID="btnbankinfo" class="btn-success" runat="server" Text="SAVE" Height="44px" Width="80px" Style="font-weight: bolder" />
                <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
                <%--<asp:Label ID="lblbankinfo" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>--%>
                <span id="bnkmsg"></span>

                <div style="color: #b94a48; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; background-color: #f2dede; border: #eed3d7 1px solid; padding: 10px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <p>
                        <b>Important Info:</b>Please ensure you SAVE each PAGE before clicking on the NEXT Button!
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <button class="btn btn-warning back6" type="button"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span>Back</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary open6" type="button" style="font-weight: bolder">Next <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </fieldset>
</div>
```

MY JAVASCRIPT FILE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnbankinfo").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var BankDetails = {};

            BankDetails.Bank = $("#ddlbankname").val();
            BankDetails.AccountNo = $("#txtaccno").val();
            BankDetails.SortCode = $("#txtsortcode").val();
            BankDetails.UserId = $("txtuserid").val();
            BankDetails.Email = $("#txtemail").val();

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
                BankDetails: BankDetails
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CustomWebService.asmx/addBank",
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnErrorCall
            });

            function OnSuccess(response) {
                var result = response.d;
                if (result == "success") {
                    $("#bnkmsg").html("Personal details addded successfully  :)").css("color", "green");
                }
                $("#ddlbankname").val("");
                $("#txtaccno").val("");
                $("#txtsortcode").val("");
                $("#txtuserid").val("");
                $("#txtemail").val("");

            }

            function OnErrorCall(response) {
                $("#bnkmsg").html("An Error has occurred. Please Try Again!").css("color", "red");
            }

        });

});
```

MY CLASS FILE:

```
public class BankDetails
{
    public int BankID { get; set; }
    public string Bank { get; set; }
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
    public string SortCode { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }    
}
```

MY WEBMETHOD:

```
[WebMethod]
public string addBank(BankDetails BankDetails)
{
    try
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NNPC-ChevronScholarshipConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))  
        //using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.conn.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "spAddBankDetails";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bank", BankDetails.Bank);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNo", BankDetails.AccountNo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortCode", BankDetails.SortCode);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", BankDetails.UserId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", BankDetails.Email);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } conn.Close();
        }
        return "success";
    }
    catch (Exception ac)
    {
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Thanks Dale for asking. The error message it displays is the one found in the JQuery Script file that it displays when it is not successful. function OnErrorCall(response) {
                $("#bnkmsg").html("An Error has occurred. Please Try Again!").css("color", "red");

Comment: What is the _actual_ error from your `response` object?

Comment: @Chris Schaller, the actual error is that it returns the error message as in the JQuery file I posted earlier rather than inserting the data and post successful message.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted your error along with the source code, I can only analyze and see one problem with it which would be causing the potential error you are facing and that is the `json` that you are sending. Notice, you are constructing your `json` data like below:

```
var BankDetails = {};

BankDetails.Bank = $("#ddlbankname").val();
BankDetails.AccountNo = $("#txtaccno").val();
BankDetails.SortCode = $("#txtsortcode").val();
BankDetails.UserId = $("txtuserid").val();
BankDetails.Email = $("#txtemail").val();

var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
    BankDetails: BankDetails
});
```

Which possibly generates this `json` as the request body:

```
{
    "BankDetails" : 
    {
        "Bank": "Some Bank",
        "AccountNo": "Some Account #",
        "SortCode": "Sort Code",
        "UserId": "1234",
        "Email": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Which, technically, won't be mapped onto the class structure that you have.

To fix this issue, you can have two solutions, the simplest and straight forward way will be to `stringify` the `json` object directly instead of adding the object into another `json` body like below:

```
var BankDetails = {};

BankDetails.Bank = $("#ddlbankname").val();
BankDetails.AccountNo = $("#txtaccno").val();
BankDetails.SortCode = $("#txtsortcode").val();
BankDetails.UserId = $("txtuserid").val();
BankDetails.Email = $("#txtemail").val();

// This line
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(BankDetails);
```

The second way would be to customize your class structure and introduce a parent class that will hold the object `BankDetails` in it, something like below:

```
public class BankDetails
{
    public int BankID { get; set; }
    public string Bank { get; set; }
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
    public string SortCode { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }    
}
public class BankDetailsParent
{
    public BankDetails BankDetails { get; set;}
}
```

Similarly, this modify the parameter of the `WebMethod` that you have:

```
[WebMethod]
public string addBank(BankDetailsParent BankDetailsParent)
{
    BankDetails BankDetails = BankDetailsParent.BankDetails; // get the bank details object.
    //  your logic here
    string doStuff = "doStuff";
    return doStuff;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnbankinfo").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var BankDetails = {};

            BankDetails.Bank = $("#ddlbankname").val();
            BankDetails.AccountNo = $("#txtaccno").val();
            BankDetails.SortCode = $("#txtsortcode").val();
            BankDetails.UserId = $("txtuserid").val();
            BankDetails.Email = $("#txtemail").val();

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(BankDetails);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CustomWebService.asmx/addBank",
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnErrorCall
            });

            function OnSuccess(response) {
                var result = response.d;
                if (result == "success") {
                    $("#bnkmsg").html("Personal details addded successfully  :)").css("color", "green");
                }
                $("#ddlbankname").val("");
                $("#txtaccno").val("");
                $("#txtsortcode").val("");
                $("#txtuserid").val("");
                $("#txtemail").val("");

            }

            function OnErrorCall(response) {
                $("#bnkmsg").html("An Error has occurred. Please Try Again!").css("color", "red");
                console.log(response); // this will contain the error you are facing.
            }
            /* Add this line here: */
            return false; // this will return false and the postback won't occur.

        });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Jamshaid for providing answers. I have used the first option provided. But it throws a postback and throws no error message but data is not inserted into database and no success message is displayed. I believe when using ajax it is not supposed to throw a post-back. The second option you provided still throws the error message(function OnErrorCall(response) { $("#bnkmsg").html("An Error has occurred. Please Try Again!").css("color", "red"); ) on submission instead of successful message.Please help out.

Comment: @Midtechltd That I suspect is because, you are not returning false in your function. Please add this statement at the end of your method `return false;` see the update in my answer.

Comment: i have done that but still get the same postback and no response and data insertion.

Comment: Check for the console if there are any errors in the console.